# kivyMD intermittent AssertionError

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

kivy 2.0.0, kivymd 0.104.2dev0, python3.7

I am having error intermittently when I add MDdatatable to new screen's MDBoxLayout with button press.

sometime get error immediately, sometime get error once out of 30 times of try.

```
AssertionError with .py and KeyError: <ParserRule name='<CommonElevationBehavior>'> with apk.
```

any one have idea where should I look?

and also have this warning too, intermittently, with button press.

```
[WARNING] <kivymd.uix.gridlayout.MDGridLayout object at 0x00000290BDE1D278> have no cols or rows set, layout is not triggered.
```

even if my all gridlayout have cols set.

here is my minimal code.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.metrics import dp
import threading, time

KV = """
   
ScreenManager:
    id : scr_mng  
    Ad_control_main_screen:
    Ad_control_detail:
    
<Ad_control_main_screen>:
    id: ad_control_main_screen
    name: 'ad_control_main_screen'
    MDFillRoundFlatButton
        text: 'detail' 
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        on_release:
            root.Adctr_detail()
   
<Ad_control_detail>
    id: ad_control_detail  
    name: "ad_control_detail"  
    
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        MDBoxLayout:
            height: self.minimum_height
            size_hint_y: None
            AnchorLayout:
                anchor_x: "center"
                anchor_y: "center"
                size_hint_y: None
                padding: [0, 5, 0, 0]
                
                MDGridLayout:
                    cols: 1
                    spacing: [10, 12]
                    size_hint: None, None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    width: self.minimum_width                
                
                    MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                        text: "back"
                        on_release:
                            root.get_back()
        MDBoxLayout:
            id: table_layout
   
"""

class Ad_control_main_screen(Screen):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        global scr_mng
        scr_mng = self.manager
        scr_mng.transition.direction = 'left'

    def Adctr_detail(self):
        scr_mng.current = 'ad_control_detail'

class Ad_control_detail(Screen):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        if self.ids.table_layout.children != []:
            self.ids.table_layout.clear_widgets()
        self.get_camData_thread()

    def get_camData_thread(self):
        get_cam_data = threading.Thread(target=self.create_table)
        get_cam_data.daemon = True
        get_cam_data.start()

    def create_table(self, *args):
        time.sleep(1)
        r_data = []
        for i in range(10):
            r_data.append((i, "data "+str(i), "data "+str(i), "data "+str(i), "data "+str(i), "data "+str(i)))

        c_data = [("", dp(5)),
                  ("colum 1", dp(30)),
                  ("colum 2", dp(15)),
                  ("colum 3", dp(15)),
                  ("colum 4", dp(15)),
                  ("colum 5", dp(15)),]

        data_table = MDDataTable(
            use_pagination=False,
            check=False,
            elevation=0,
            column_data=c_data,
            row_data=r_data,
            rows_num=int(len(r_data))
        )
        self.ids.table_layout.add_widget(data_table)

    def get_back(self):
        scr_mng.transition.direction = 'right'
        scr_mng.current = 'ad_control_main_screen'

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Ad_control_main_screen(name='ad_control_main_screen'))
sm.add_widget(Ad_control_detail(name='ad_control_detail'))

class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


Test().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the thread, you must limit what you do in that thread. Some operations must be performed on the main thread. Here is a modified version of your `Ad_control_detail` class that does that:

```
class Ad_control_detail(Screen):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        if self.ids.table_layout.children != []:
            self.ids.table_layout.clear_widgets()
        self.get_camData_thread()

    def get_camData_thread(self):
        get_cam_data = threading.Thread(target=self.create_table)
        get_cam_data.daemon = True
        get_cam_data.start()

    def add_table(self, r_data, c_data, dt):
        # This does the operations that must be on the main thread
        data_table = MDDataTable(
            use_pagination=False,
            check=False,
            column_data=c_data,
            row_data=r_data,
            rows_num=int(len(r_data))
        )
        self.ids.table_layout.add_widget(data_table)

    def create_table(self, *args):
        # this does the operations that may be done on another thread
        time.sleep(1)
        r_data = []
        for i in range(10):
            r_data.append((i, "data " + str(i), "data " + str(i), "data " + str(i), "data " + str(i), "data " + str(i)))

        c_data = [("", dp(5)),
                  ("colum 1", dp(30)),
                  ("colum 2", dp(15)),
                  ("colum 3", dp(15)),
                  ("colum 4", dp(15)),
                  ("colum 5", dp(15)), ]
        
        # run the add_table() method on the main thread
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.add_table, r_data, c_data))

    def get_back(self):
        scr_mng.transition.direction = 'right'
        scr_mng.current = 'ad_control_main_screen'
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that you are making changes to the GUI on a thread other than the main thread. Try changing:

```
class Ad_control_detail(Screen):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        if self.ids.table_layout.children != []:
            self.ids.table_layout.clear_widgets()
        self.get_camData_thread()
```

to:

```
class Ad_control_detail(Screen):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        if self.ids.table_layout.children != []:
            self.ids.table_layout.clear_widgets()
        # self.get_camData_thread()
        self.create_table()
```

I think you also need to remove `elevation=0,` from the `MDDataTable` creation command.

Comment: but what if I stiil need to use thread? how should I use thread right?
in actual code, there is tons of data and have to get it from my sql server. it tooks maybe 1~6 seconds. If I don't use thread main thread freezes. 
so I made main thread ro run progressbar and mean while another thread to get datas.
that is why I need to use thread

Comment: Do everything except adding the widget to the GUI in the new thread, then use `Clock.schedule_once()` to call a method that just does the `add_widget()`.